# pass postgres connection to multiple functions

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to create a function that connects to my psql DB "function connectDB(){ }" using pg_pconnect() , and i have multiple functions that do select/ update queries, I am sending the connection as parameter =in these functions to decrease creating multiple connections:

```
function connectDB() {
    $conStr = "host=" . DB_HOST . " dbname=" . DB_NAME . " user=" . DB_USER . "    password=" . DB_PASS;
     $connection = pg_pconnect($conStr);
     return $connection;
}
```

---

```
function selectDB($connection) {
    $ids = '2,34,56,5,555';
    .
    .
    .
    ....
    $query = "SELECT from users where id IN ($ids)";
    $result = pg_query($connection, $query);

}
```

am getting this error:
invalid connection resource id#14
I think the connection is closed before the query is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider how to make a data access layer in your code. Something like this

```
class dal{

private $connection;

function connectDB() {
    $conStr = "host=" . DB_HOST . " dbname=" . DB_NAME . " user=" . DB_USER . "    password=" . DB_PASS;
     $this->connection = pg_pconnect($conStr);
}

function selectDB($ids) {
    .
    .
    .
    ....
    $query = "SELECT from users where id IN ($ids)";
    $result = pg_query($this->connection, $query);
    return $result;
}

}
```

now use an instance of this dalin your code.
Use the industry standards to make your life easier.